# Copy a table data from one database to another database SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have had a look at similar problems, however none of the answers helped in my case.

Just a little bit of background. I have Two databases, both have the same table with the same fields and structure. Data already exists in both tables. I want to overwrite and add to the data in db1.table from db2.table the primary ID is causing a problem with the update.

When I use the query:

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO db2.table(field_id,field1,field2)
SELECT table.field_id,table.field1,table.field2
FROM table;
```

It works to a blank table, because none of the primary keys exist. As soon as the primary key exists it fails.

Would it be easier for me to overwrite the primary keys? or find the primary key and update the fields related to the field_id? Im really not sure how to go ahead from here. The data needs to be migrated every 5min, so possibly a stored procedure is required?

Comment: why the data should be migrated if already exists?

Comment: Overwrite existing data or only add new rows? Check if your DBMS supports `MERGE`.

Comment: you can use `UPDATE` instead

Comment: @Qwerty: Very good question. Why don't he use a view in db2 instead?

Comment: @qwerty the data is modified into one database, but needs to be moved to another database for a different program. Both databases are a MariaDB and on the same server, using HeidiSQL to manage.

Comment: To overwrite or `UPDATE` you need a key (primary or unique) to say _which_ row to overwrite/update.

Answer (score 1):

first you should  try to add new records then update all records.you can create a procedure like below code

```
PROCEDURE sync_Data(a IN NUMBER ) IS
  BEGIN

   insert into db2.table
     select *
       from db1.table t
         where t.field_id not in (select tt.field_id from db2.table tt);

     begin
       for t in (select * from   db1.table) loop
        update db2.table aa
         set aa.field1  = t.field1,
           aa.field2     = t.field2 
     where aa.field_id = t.field_id;
  end loop;
 end;

END sync_Data
```

Comment: The traditional approach is to Update the EXISTS rows first and then Insert/Select the NOT EXISTS, but without loop. Btw, when you rewrite the Insert into another loop it's even more inefficient.

Comment: you say true. @dnoeth

Answer (score 0):

Set ***IsIdentity*** to **No** in ***Identity Specification*** on the table in which you want to move data, and after executing your script, set it to **Yes** again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just removing the data in the new database and sending it again.

```
DELETE FROM db2.table WHERE db2.table.field_id != 0;
USE db1;
INSERT INTO db2.table(field_id,field1,field2)
SELECT table.field_id,table.field1,table.field2
FROM table;
```

Its not very efficient, but gets the job done. I couldnt figure out the syntax to correctly do an UPDATE or to change the IsIdentity field within MariaDB, so im not sure if they would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of deleting and replacing non-trivial amounts of data for an entire table will be prohibitive.  That said I'd prefer to update in place (merge) over delete /replace.

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO db2.table(field_id,field1,field2)
SELECT t.field_id,t.field1,t.field2
FROM table t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = t.field1, field2 = t.field2
```

This can be used inside a procedure and called every 5 minutes (not recommended) or you could build a trigger that fires on INSERT and UPDATE to keep the tables in sync.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO database1.tabledata SELECT * FROM database2.tabledata;
```

But you have to keep length of varchar length larger or equal to database2 and keep the same column name